# Deploy rails app on dotcloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dotcloud

I'm trying to deploy a ruby on rails app to dotcloud. The app is deployed but when I try to access the url, I get this error:

could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"? (PG::Error)

I'm using a postgresql database. What all changes do I need to make in the database.yml file?

I've also followed the steps outlined here:
http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/postgresql/

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app is configured to use a local PostgreSQL database (local as in "running on the same machine"). You should make sure that your `dotcloud.yml` file contains a section for a PosgreSQL database, e.g.:

```
db:
  type: postgresql
```

Then use either `dotcloud info` to retrieve the host, port, and credentials of the database, or parse them from `environment.json` in your Ruby app.

This last step is explained in the [dotCloud PostgreSQL service documentation](http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/postgresql/#configure-your-application).